# Are objective questions that result in game lists on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic, top-7

I'm thinking of this question:

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/83/largest-number-of-components-in-the-box

This question isn't subjective -- some game will have the most components.  But on the other hand, it's likely this question will just result in a big list of answers listing games and their component numbers.  It inherently can't settle on a "right" answer because somebody else can always show up with a more obscure game with more components.

And voting for answers to this kind of question is meaningless - votes accumulate for the current "winner" in component count, but then a higher count answer is posted and it has to accumulate enough votes to pass that earlier answer.

I just don't think this kind of question makes sense in this forum.

Comment: I think that "Subjective" is the answer.  There is a question about "What are good cooperative games..."  This results in a list of many games from different users.  And I would believe this to be 'on topic'.

Comment: There is a difference between a recommendations question (which I think we will call on-topic, and is on-topic at Gaming) and this kind of list.  Both can or should be community wiki ultimately, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those lists should be Community Wiki, if anything.  I don't think we have mods yet so we won't have CW posts.

Use your votes to close for anything you find objectionable.  If 4 people agree, it will close.

Answer (score 6):

Subjective or not, [the question you linked](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/83/largest-number-of-components-in-the-box) simply provides no value. It's straight-up, one-liner trivia.

If you look to the "guidelines" [**in this blog post**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), it will help you separate polls asked to solve a problem versus mindless social typing.

Comment: I guess my question, then, is how we label a close request on this kind of question?  It's not actually subjective, it's just useless.  That one was closed `too localized` but even that doesn't really seem like the right reason.  I guess it's really just off-topic?

Comment: I would probably close as as [not a real question]. It's a "real question" in the sense that it has a question mark, but it's not *real* because WHO THE \*bleep\* CARES.